# Unused node detected when configuring schedule block with ant for CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I'm developing a ccnet.config script for CruiseControl.net that invokes an Ant script, and I'm getting the following error while executing the CruiseControl.NET service:

Error: "Unused node detected:schedule block"

This is my ccnet.config:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/5">
  <project name="testprj">
    <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet</webURL>
    <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds>
    <sourcecontrol type="cvs" autoGetSource="true">
      <executable>C:\dev\ccnet\ccnet\tools\cvs.exe</executable>
      <cvsroot>:ext:exortech@ccnet:/cvsroot/ccnetcontrib</cvsroot>
      <module>ccnet</module>
      <workingDirectory>C:\dev\Copy of FAT\</workingDirectory>
      <webUrlBuilder type="viewcvs">
        <url>http://localhost:7899/viewcvs/ccnet/NUnitDemo/</url>
      </webUrlBuilder>
    </sourcecontrol>
    <schedule>
      <ant>
        <antscript>C:\Apache\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin\ant.bat</antscript>
        <antworkingdir>C:\Apache</antworkingdir>
        <buildfile>internalpush.xml</buildfile>
        <uselogger>true</uselogger>
        <usedebug>false</usedebug>
      </ant>
    </schedule>
    <publishers>
      <merge>
        <files>
          <file>C:\dev\ccnet\ccnet\build\ccnet.exe-results.xml</file>
        </files>
      </merge>
      <xmllogger>
        <logDir>log</logDir>
      </xmllogger>
      <email mailhost="foo" from="sreekanth@foo.com" includeDetails="true">
        <users>
          <user name="BuildGuru" group="buildmaster" address="buildguru@mycompany.com"/>
          <user name="JoeDeveloper" group="developers" address="joedeveloper@thoughtworks.com"/>
        </users>
        <groups>
          <group name="developers">
            <notifications>
              <NotificationType>Change</NotificationType>
            </notifications>
          </group>
          <group name="buildmaster">
            <notifications>
              <NotificationType>Change</NotificationType>
            </notifications>
          </group>
        </groups>
      </email>
    </publishers>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "schedule" element available under the "project" element: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Configuration+Block

Comment: Thanks dude. Now i'm choosed <exec> block for execute ant script.